# Set WordPress default post_type post with a slug without using admin Permalink Settings

Tags: wordpress

For a client, they'd like all their posts, which reside under the `post_type => post` within WordPress to have the `blog/` prefix to them.

I know this is doable by going to `Settings -> Permalinks` and changing the value to `blog/%postname%`. However doing so, if a client updated a page from `About (slug about)` to `About Us (slug about-us)`, WordPress will not redirect the slug `about` to `about-us` if I change the Permalink settings.

I've looking into inserting an array into the `rewrite` of the `post` args, but this didn't resolve anything. I've also looked into using [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/), but again this did not resolve the issue, as it was unable to actively monitor the slug changes, even with the Options updated within the plugin.

Does anyone know of a function I can hook into, or a solution? Googling this seems to only tackle custom post types, which I am not altering.

Comment: Do you want post slug as blog?

Comment: Yes, for the default post_type `post` to have the slug `blog` before their postname. so like `domain.com/blog/hello-world` (post) while `domain.com/about` (page) is able to xfer to `domain.com/about-us` if the client decides they wanna change the page slug.

Comment: @developerme did you have a possible solution?